# Deferred-length character support by Intel Fortran Compiler 14.0.3

Tags: fortran, standards, intel-fortran, fortran2003

Does Intel Fortran Compiler support the Fortran 2003 feature, 'deferred-length character'? If so, has it already been supported by the compiler version 14.0.3? (*)

This page,
[Fortran 2003 Features, Intel Developer Zone](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/581568),
says that

> "Fortran 2003 is fully supported, including the following features:"

but the subsequent list includes

> - Allocatable scalar variables (not deferred-length character)

This does not seem to clarify whether 'deferred-length character' is a supported feature. Furthermore, the page seems to refer to the latest version, 16.

I got a hint that it is supported as following. I tried compiling the code which seems to use deferred-length character in [the answer by IanH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091917/883431) to the question,
[Using a deferred-length character string to read user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084087/using-a-deferred-length-character-string-to-read-user-input),
by `ifort` of that version and it ran successfully.
Nevertheless, I wish to know where I can find some official documentation by Intel about the status of implementation of the Fortran standards at each version of the compiler. I thought such a document may be included in the document directory of the product, but I could not find one.

---

(*) Edited 2015-11-15

The first paragraph of the question originally read as following:
"Does Intel Fortran Compiler support all the Fortran 2003 features? If so, since when? More specifically, if I would like to know if the compiler version 14.0.3 supports the 'deferred-length character'."
I rewrote it according to the comment by francescalus.

Comment: I suggest removing the question about full 2003 support.  Knowing, say, that 15.0.3 was the first version supporting all features (and that bugs even in 16.0 mean that it still isn't compliant with that standard) doesn't really help with your specific question about deferred-length character variables and 14.0.3.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the comment. I agree and rewrote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred length character has been supported for some years now by Intel Fortran, several versions before 14.0.3.

In the documentation for 13.1, which is the oldest version I have installed, the deferred length character feature is documented on the "Declarations for character types" page.

Comment: In the same document (the user guide for 16.0) as in the question the section referenced in the answer [addresses whether it really does support deferred-length](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/579886).

Comment: IanH and francescalus Thank you for your answer and comment. I also found the description in my local 14.0.3 documentation. Let me note the precise path here for my later reference. It is in the document 'User and Reference Guide for the Intel Fortran Compiler 14.0' and in the section, 'Language Reference/Specification Statements/Type Declarations/Declarations for Character Types'