# How to get command line arguments of unknown length in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, string, fortran

I'd like to read in some text strings from the command line used to run a program. I'm using the internal subroutine `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT` in a program that basically is something like:

```
program test
character(len=100) :: argument
call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,argument)
print*, argument
end program test
```

The issue here is that I feel it's a bit dangerous to set the maximum length of the string at compilation time. Some of the arguments are typically files with their path, so they might be very long. A solution involving setting the length statically to 1000 sounds like an ugly workaround.

Isn't there a more elegant way in Fortran to define a string able to contain a chain of characters whose length is only known at run time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to use what are called deferred-length character variables.  These are not of a fixed constant length and their use can be found in questions such as [a related one about data input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31084087).

However, even with a deferred length variable used like (for this is the syntax)

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: argument
allocate(character(some_length) :: argument)  ! For integer some_length
call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,argument)
print*, argument
end
```

one still has to worry about what `some_length` should be.  If we just choose 100, we're back to where we were.

We have to worry about this because `get_command_argument` as is currently widely implemented doesn't take such a deferred length argument and allocate it to the desired length.  That is

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: argument
call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,argument)  ! Will argument be allocated in the subroutine?
print*, argument
end
```

offers the answer "no".<sup>1</sup>

Coming, then, to a way to handle this, we look at other (optional) arguments to `get_command_argument`.  In particular, there is one called `length`:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: argument
integer arglen
call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,length=arglen)
allocate(character(arglen) :: argument)
call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,value=argument)
print*, argument
end
```

Naturally, one could create a wrapper subroutine which did take an allocatable deferred length character variable and did all that work.

---

<sup>1</sup> Fortran 2023 changes the behaviour of intrinsic procedures which take character variables. `get_command_argument`, along with many others, in this language revision does now allocate such a deferred-length character. Where the answer was "no" before Fortran 2023 is now "yes". Practically, though, we'll be writing portable Fortran code assuming the answer is "no" for many years yet.

Comment: Your approach is much better, somehow I forgot this argument.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that this approach works also for `get_environment_variable`.

Comment: Thanks, this is of great help and indeed solves the question. I have just a minor question, why is it necessary the rather convoluted `allocate(character(some_length) :: argument)` instead of the more simple `allocate(argument(some_length))`

Comment: @Onturenio The latter syntax is for arrays. Consider an array of characters `allocate(character(char_len) :: argument(array_len))`.

Comment: @Onturenio To add to Vladimir F's comment, the `allocate( type-spec :: ...)` form is used to set the type and type parameters on the allocation.  The character variable's length is a type parameter.  You may see this syntax also for polymorphic variables to set the dynamic type or for parameterized derived types.

Answer (score 2):

I will leave this for completeness, it may be useful to somebody, but francescalus' answer is much better.

Basically, just read it with some default length, check the `STATUS` variable and if it did not fit, try again.

From the gcc manual:

> If the argument retrieval fails, STATUS is a positive number; if VALUE
>   contains a truncated command line argument, STATUS is -1; and
>   otherwise the STATUS is zero.

So:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: argument
integer :: stat, n

n = 100
allocate(character(n) :: argument)

do
  call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,argument, status=stat)
  if (stat>=0) exit
  deallocate(argument)
  n = n * 2
  allocate(character(n) :: argument)
end do

if (stat>0) error...

argument = trim(argument)

print*, argument
```